# How can I find questions on a meta site that are missing any of the required tags

Tags: support, search, tag-search

I'm trying to help out on a meta site by cleaning up old questions that are missing any of the required meta tags. My search-fu is failing me, however.

I tried this in the search box:

```
-[discussion] -[bug] -[support] -[feature-request]
```

That gives me the failed search page.

Similarly, editing the URL to

```
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/-discussion+-bug+-support+-feature-request
```

Just redirects me to `http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions`.

I *thought* I had a good handle on searching for tags and negating terms, but apparently not. What's the secret sauce?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You gotta add a positive search term as well.

For example, `is:question`:

`-[discussion] -[bug] -[support] -[feature-request] is:question`